# Jupyternotebook corrects groupby to groupyouby Python

Tags: python, jupyter

I don't know how this happens or why,

but I'll be in a jupyter notebook grouping by things and I will very conciously type in dataframe.groupby, write some other code and hit ctrl+ enter
and there will be that damn error. Every single time, I will go back and delete the 'groupyouby' and type in groupby.

I doubt that anyone has run into this error,and I don't know how long it will be until someone else creates the mess of libraries that I have that resulted in this chinese water tourture like nightmare. I am here, to let you know, that you are not alone.

*Also if someone has a fix that would be great. I got nothing for you other than that description above.*

Comment: It may be a browser extension, try disabling them. There is nothing that ctrl+enter triggers to rewrite the cell,so it's likely not due to your libraries.

Comment: YOU"RE RIGHT! it's grammarly that ruins jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammarly was the cause of this. 
If you use jupyter notebooks and have the grammarly extension. It *will cause problems*.